# Why do i get connection reset by peer error when i try to use yomu with Amazon S3 to fetch text?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3

I have been trying to get yomu to work with Amazon S3 and get text directly from a URL. I followed the yomu documentation to try the same

```
(Yomu.new "https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/files/uploads/961/original/myFile.pdf").text
```

I then get the following error

```
Errno::ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer):
```

However, I am able to upload and download files from S3 using the same link and uploading to s3 also works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not figure the solution out to run yomu directly off the s3 path. Hence i used open-uri to first download the file temporarily to my local and then run yomu on the temp path before deleting the file of my local.